# Route blank to child component with id

Tags: angular

I expect `www.mypage.com/users` to be routed to `www.mypage.com/users/1`, how can this be achieved?

I tried following

```
 path: 'users', redirectTo: '1', pathMatch: 'full', children: [     
  { path: ':id', component: UsersComponent }
]
```

I could also return 404 page but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using adding one more child route with `''`(blank) path check inside child route. But you have to create an parent component which template would have `router-outlet` once again.

```
{
  path: 'users', component: UserWrapperComponent, 
    children: [
       { path: '', redirectTo: '1', pathMatch: 'full' }
       { path: ':id', component: UsersComponent }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It worked, but I had to remove pathMatch from first path, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
{path: 'users', redirectTo: 'users/1', pathMatch: 'full', children: [     
  { path: '1', component: UsersComponent }
]
```